# Metrizability of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If we have a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and a metric $d$ on $X$ s.t. for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ convergence of the sequence $x_n$ to some $x \in X$ for the topology $\mathcal{T}$ is equivalent to $d(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$ do we then have that the topology induced by the metric $d$ is $\mathcal{T}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set, let $\tau$ be the co-countable topology on $X$, and let $d$ be the discrete metric on $X$ defined by

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
1,&\text{if }x\ne y\;.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is not metrizable, but $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ in $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ iff $\sigma$ is eventually constant at $x$ iff $\langle d(x_n,x):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to 0$.

Comment: @Holymonk: You're very welcome!